# How to figure out where in a questline I am?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am trying to get my Legion flying, and for that I need the "A Glorious Campaign" achievement. However, I abandoned this long ago as I did not play much during Legion. Now I am trying to figure out where in the quest chain I am, and I'm totally lost. I use Carbonite, and am willing to use other addons to assist in the process. I am a Paladin, but an ideal answer would work for other classes trying to do other quest-lines

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my problem using two resources - first, an addon called Quest Completionist. It provides a very intuitive interface into my quest history - much more so than Carbonite, even if it has far fewer features. Second, I just look up the quest lines on Wowhead and search in there for the quests. Using a binary search I was able to quickly find the first quest in the chain I had not completed. I used this in multiple chains and the process was fairly smooth.